# Compass function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm a beginner when it comes to MATLAB and I'm trying to plot a set of points using compass while holding on the plot. The problem is that when I, for example, plot the first point and then plot a second point that is "far away", the compass axes don't get updated. Is there a way to re-size the axes so that I can get the second point wihtin the frame?

Example :

```
compass(1,2);
hold on;
compass(40,50);%that point is out of the frame and I can't see the whole arrow
```

Thanks !

Comment: in all the polar type plots (`polar`, `compass`, `rose`, ...). The polar grid is not the graduation of the `axes` itself, it is composed by a `patch` and a set of `line`s and `text`s objects, which are calculated and positioned the first time the function is called on a figure. They will not be dynamically adjusted. To make sure you'll have all your data fitting in the makeshift grid, call `compass` **on the maximum element** first.

Comment: @Hoki Would you mind posting this comment as an answer so that I would mark the answer the question as answered, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from @Hoki (so as to mark the subject as solved) :

In all the polar type plots (polar, compass, rose, ...). The polar grid is not the graduation of the axes itself, it is composed by a patch and a set of lines and texts objects, which are calculated and positioned the first time the function is called on a figure. They will not be dynamically adjusted. To make sure you'll have all your data fitting in the makeshift grid, call compass on the maximum element first.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you simply store the coordinates in vectors first and then plot them all at once.

```
   a = [1,40];
   b = [2,50];
   compass(a,b)
```

Comment: well let just say that I want ow to do it (before figuring it's impossible) for a pure intellectual joy and not for the very sake of how to cope with the situation. And thank you for the comment ^-^

Comment: I can appreciate that, but please mark the question as answered since it seems your issue is resolved :)